# Getting DDNS to work on a a WL-500g premium for a private network

Tags: wireless-networking

I'd like to set up [DDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) for my home network, e.g. allow the home computers to have short names such as:

- desktop.at.home
- laptop.at.home

Is this possible with an [WL-500g](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=8el2DcrRjLoHNdQ8&templete=2)?

To put it another way, can I configure it as a DDNS *server* for the private network?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note here.  There might be a much easier way to do this.  If you do not need these addresses to resolve via the network,  you can add the name you wish to your host file with the desired IP address.  This works like a champ if the IP address will remain constant.  Since the communications protocol will try to resolve the name locally via the host file first, you can add it there and it will work great.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the router does tend to change IPs from time to time and it's cumbersome to propagate hosts file across the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DynDNS](https://www.dyndns.com/) for this. What happens is, the software will update the DynDNS website with your IP address every time you connect. As you know, packets sent from behind the router will have the router's IP address after passing through it since it is your gateway. The site allows you to choose subdomains as you specify (such as `home-desktop.dyndns.com`), so you can either use a different port for each computer, or use multiple DynDNS names.

Comment: How would this work?  If the OP is on their laptop, and want to connect to their desktop, the DynDNS wouldn't appear to help?  It'd be the same as trying to connect to their router directly?  You mention ports, so port forwarding might assist in getting to the right system, but they mention that their using dynamic IPs, so that doesn't seem viable either, especially if you want to use different services on the intranet?